# Как обратится к объекту из метода обьекта

Tags: javascript

Не могу красиво описать, так что лучше покажу на примере.
В примере ниже при срабатывании события this будет ссылаться на DOM элемент, от которого событие сработали.
Как в таком случае получить доступ к объекту не зная его имя.

```
object = {

    method : function(){
        this
    }

};

myObject = Object.create(object);


$('someone').click(myObject.method)
```

Comment: В итоге нашел выход в виде такой конструкции:

element.bind('click', {object: this}, function(event){ 
  object = event.data.object;
  object.changeSlide(this);
});

Answer (score 1):

```
object = {

    method : function(obj){

        console.log($(obj).attr('class'));
    }

};

myObject = Object.create(object);


$('.class').bind('click',function(){myObject.method(this);});
```

Answer (score 1):

Привязать метод к конкретному объекту можно вызовом [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
object = {
    method : function(){
        this
    }
};

myObject = Object.create(object);

$('someone').click(myObject.method.bind(myObject));
```